# How to fix the wait operation is timed out? Works some time but is not working finely

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I m a learner of MVC and has very limited knowledge. This is working but too slow.
Here are my few questions.

1.Does using the controller instead of the API degrade the performance?

2.Are there any cons to implementing an individual search for each column?

3.What is bad practice in this code? How can I correct them?

4.Table compounds have more than 200k rows. how can I make it as fast as possible with Ajaxified search, sortable, individual search for each column and pagination?

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult AjaxCompound(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        IQueryable<Compound> allCompounds = _context.Compounds.Include(p => p.Oil);
        IEnumerable<Compound> filteredCompounds;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            filteredCompounds = allCompounds
                     .Where(c => c.Oil.CommonName.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 //||
                                 //c.Oil.BotanicalName.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                                 c.Name.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                                 c.RI.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                  ||
                                 c.MolecularWeight.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                                 c.MolecularFormula.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                  ||
                                 c.AreaPercent.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 );
        }
        else
        {
            filteredCompounds = allCompounds;
        }

        var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        Func<Compound, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 ? c.Oil.CommonName :
                                                           //sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.Oil.BotanicalName :
                                                           sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.Name :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 3 ? c.RI :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 4 ? c.MolecularFormula :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 5 ? c.MolecularWeight :
                                                            c.AreaPercent);



        var commonFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_1"]);
        //var botanicalFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_2"]);
        var name = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_2"]);
        var rI = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_3"]);
        var mW = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_4"]);
        var mF = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_5"]);
        var areaPercent = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_6"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commonFilter))
        {
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.Oil.CommonName.Contains(commonFilter));

        }

        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(botanicalFilter))
        //{
        //    filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.Oil.BotanicalName.Contains(botanicalFilter));

        //}


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rI))
        {
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.RI.Contains(rI));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mF))
        {
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.MolecularFormula.Contains(mF));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mW))
        {
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.MolecularWeight.Contains(mW));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaPercent))
        {
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.Where(c => c.AreaPercent.Contains(areaPercent));

        }

        var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"];
        if (sortDirection == "asc")
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
        else
            filteredCompounds = filteredCompounds.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

        var displayedCompounds = filteredCompounds
                           .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
                           .Take(param.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedCompounds
                     select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.PaperId), c.Oil.CommonName, /*c.Oil.BotanicalName,*/ c.Name, c.RI, c.MolecularWeight, c.MolecularFormula, c.AreaPercent };
        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = allCompounds.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCompounds.Count(),
            aaData = result
        },
                         JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: they are saying, "You can only post once every 40 minutes.". :(